# c# REST service Post will not respond?

Tags: c#, rest

I have a C# solution which has a REST service project which uses another Class Library project. If I send a GET request, the service responds correctly. But, if I send a **POST**, the service's Post implementation works correctly inserting data in a database. However I receive no response status code (**200 OK**) at the client end (Fiddler). Below you will find the code. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace OwinSelfhostSample
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        DatabaseConnector2.DatabaseLibrary database;

        // POST api/values 
        public void Post(Command command)
        {
            //create connection object and insert data
            database = new DatabaseConnector2.DatabaseLibrary(command.Instruction, command.Cell);
        }

        // GET api/values 
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
}
```

The Post resource calls the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace DatabaseConnector2
{
    public class DatabaseLibrary
    {

        // Holds our connection with the database
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        Data_connection dbobject;

        // Only for testing
        //static void Main(string[] args)
        //{
        //    DatabaseLibrary p = new DatabaseLibrary("hola", "chao");
        //}

        public DatabaseLibrary(string instr, string cell)
        {
            //createNewDatabase();
            connectToDatabase(); 
            //createTable();                 
            insertDataInTable(instr, cell);
            printRecords();
        }
...
}
}
```

Comment: What response status(HttpStatusCode) you are receiving? You should get a 201 or 200.

Comment: `200 OK` is what you would except. Do you mean you want to have something like an OK status also returned?

Comment: Hi, from the **Get** resource I receive 200 OK. From the **Post** resource, I receive nothing. It executes correctly, but no response.

Comment: And why dont you simply 'return Ok()' in your Post-method?

Comment: Hi SmartDev, Yes!, though it works correctly I would like to receive a **200 OK** status code at the client.

Comment: Hi DevHew, I tried to do so, but I does not return nothing at all. In summary, this **Post** resource receives and implements (executes insertion in database) the request correctly, but it does not respond to the client.

Comment: What _do_ you see in Fiddler when you highlight the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in my code. I basically had a line at the end of the code  `Console.ReadLine();` which prevented the Post resource from finishing.
Thanks to all of you !